# Nexus public repository index not picking up un-indexed repositories

Tags: maven, nexus

I setup a public repository in nexus which contains the groups of repositories we wish to access.  We then use this as our main index in Eclipse for development and Bamboo for build.

I am adding in a couple of ZK repositories to this public repository - these repos have no indexes, and are unable to be scraped by Nexus.  I presume this will prevent artifacts in them from being found.  I have rebuilt the index for public in Nexus and in Eclipse with no luck.

Can I add the repositories in the setting.xml in eclipse? Currently this looks like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <servers>
    <server>
        <id>nexus</id>
        <username>username</username>
        <password>xxxx</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <!--This sends everything else to /public -->
      <id>nexus</id>
      <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
      <url>http://<ip>:8400/nexus/content/groups/public</url>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>nexus</id>
      <!--Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
      <!--all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
     <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <id>central</id>
          <url>http://central</url>
          <releases><enabled>true</enabled></releases>
          <snapshots><enabled>true</enabled></snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <!--make the profile active all the time -->
    <activeProfile>nexus</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 1):

Search indexes are an optional repository feature. They are not used for artifact retrieval, they are used to support interactive search in UI's. Nexus will be able to pull artifacts from these proxy repositories without any problem.  As artifacts are downloaded from the remote into the proxy repository's disk cache they will be added to the local search index.